# PHP - Grabbing info from the database (complicated)

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help. I need to grab all rows which contain their logged in ID from a database. Basically, I have a column in the database called "owners" and in it it has a few IDs. Lets say "1, 6, 8", If user ID 6 is logged in, I need to grab that row. If it doesn't contain 6, say "2, 5, 7" then don't grab it. My wording probably isn't good.

```
--------------------------------
ID |Name    |Other Info |Owners|
---|--------|-----------|------|
1  |Testing |Testing 123|1,4,6 |
---|--------|-----------|------|
2  |Testing1|Catz       |5,7,8 |
---|--------|=-----------------|
3  |Testing2|Woof       |6,9,10|
---|--------|-----------|------|
```

In other words:

- User ID 6 logs in.
- Goes to page which needs the rows to be grabbed.
- Script grabs rows 1 and 3 (because the owners list contains 6).
- PHP foreach, showing the resutls in a table. (Don't need help with
  this).

The reason I want this is I don't want `ownerid2`, `ownerid3`, `ownerid4` taking up loads of space in separate columns in the database.

Comment: Google "database normalization"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(?, Owners);
```

where `?` has to be replaced with the user id, for example

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET(6, Owners);
```

as other pointed out, you might also want to read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), and here is the docs for [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Answer (score 0):

could this possibly be what you're after?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Owners LIKE '%6%';
```

????

EDIT: doing it this way would pull up other owners like 68, 600, 6123. you should look into database normalization.

EDIT2:

just thought of this, since there's no spaces between your commas you could use the explode(); function like so:

```
$ownerid = //WHATEVER THE OWNERS ID IS
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Owners LIKE '%$ownerid%'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $owners = $data['Owners'];
    $owners = explode(',',$data);
    if(in_array($ownerid, $owners){
        //SHOW ROW DATA HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: That's better. However, DB normalization is a cleaner approach. As a workaround, a correct parsing of the column contents would me more approriate, but that implies either two queries or the use of (more complicated) stored procs.

Comment: not if you put it in as a string in between the `%`s then it will return only the IDs that have exactly 65 in there so it would pull 65, 165, 1765934, etc.

Comment: @Stah The FIND_IN_SET I suggested should work even better, let MySQL do the string manipulation for you.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to accomplish this is to use a separate table for the owner relationship.

```
Table = Owner, has ID.
Table = Test, what you are currently trying to get
Table = OwnerTestRel, has a foreign key to Owner and one to Test.
```

Then your query can become something like

```
Select test.* 
FROM test
JOIN OwnerTestRel ON test.id=OwnerTestRel.testId
WHERE OwnerTestRel.ownerId = {owner's Id}
```